# Looking for record in Android SQlite Database by String

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

```
public boolean findContact(String phoneNumber) {
        boolean exists = false;
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_PHONENUMBER + " = " + phoneNumber, null);
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            exists = true;
        } else exists = false;
        return exists;
}
```

It is supose to return true when a row with telephone number exists (format is +441212312312 - String ). The problem is that it always return false, even if such a row exists. I think that a problem is with WHERE clause, but LIKE don't work either. How can I do this ? 
thanks for your response

Comment: You should do database queries within a try catch.  Also, what is KEY_PHONENUMBER and phonenumber?

Comment: KEY_PHONENUMBER is a column name and phoneNumber is a String parameter given to this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you that use query, insert, update or delete clauses directly from SQLiteDatabase object instance ;)

And see link below to know which values you will have returned

[SQLiteDatabase Object](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

And i suggest too that if you just want if it exists don't ask about * ... ask about _id because it's primary key it has a index ;)) <-- it means faster

Here i seek a specific row:

```
    public Cursor getEnvio(final String empresa_p, final String albaran_p) {
    return db.query(Envio.KEY_ENVIO, new String[] { Envio.KEY_ID,
            Envio.KEY_ALBARAN, Envio.KEY_LINEA, Envio.KEY_TIPO,
            Envio.KEY_DESTINATARIO, Envio.KEY_DIR, Envio.KEY_POBLACION,
            Envio.KEY_POBLACION, Envio.KEY_PRIORIDAD, Envio.KEY_INCIDENCIA,
            Envio.KEY_EMP, Envio.KEY_CPOSTAL }, Envio.KEY_EMP + " = ? AND "
            + Envio.KEY_ALBARAN + " = ? ", new String[] { empresa_p,
            albaran_p }, null, null, Envio.KEY_LINEA);
}
```

Comment: I know I can use _id, but I have to synchronize data so I im comparing it to unique telephone number. Anyway it started working somehow.